# How can i filter few repeatation in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql table like below. It used to store document with versioning.

[image]

I want to select a docid  of latest (with higest major version and minor version). It will eleminate all same doc id only fetch the document with highest major_version & minor_version. So i want result as below.

[image]

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: And: do you have a primary key in the table?

Comment: its mysql 5.6, and no primary key.

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data, expected output data, and your first attempts. Please edit your question to contain all this information in readable format (not as images)

Comment: Note that if you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table

Comment: @Strawberry Primary key is recommended but not mandatory, you need to know the entire database structure to comment on a table.

Comment: So, how's about that PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can filter with `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id, docid order by major_version, minor_version) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can filter with a correlated subquery. Assuming that you have a primary key in the table, say column `pk`, you can do:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.pk = (
    select t1.pk
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id and t1.docid = t.docid
    order by t1.major_version desc, t1.minor_version desc 
    limit 1
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(id, docid, major_version, minor_version)`.

Without a unique column that can be used as primary key, it is a bit more complicated. One way to do it is to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.id = t.id 
        and t1.docid = t.docid
        and (
            t1.major_version > t.major_version
            or (t1.major_version = t.major_version and t1.minor_version > t.minor_version)
        )
)
```

Comment: @SurjyadebGanguly: see the suggested index in my answer. However I would expect the last query to be a little more less efficient, because of the `OR`ed conditions. You really want a primary key in your table.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by docid order by major_version desc, minor_version desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is a pain in earlier versions.  Probably the simplest and most efficient method is to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = docid, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := docid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by docid, major_version desc, minor_version desc
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @d := '') params
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your answer but here mysql version is 5.6. So can you please suggest what i can do on that?